# Referencing a base types control template in xaml

Tags: wpf, combobox, styles, controltemplate

I have a control derived from `ComboBox`, I want to use the `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate`, and just set a few values on it in xaml, namely the `ItemContainerStyle`. The code below doesn't work, the last setter, which im intending to apply the base `ComboBox` control template to this one, doesn't do anything.

```
   <Style
      TargetType="{x:Type local:EditingFilteringComboBox}"
      BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
      <Setter
         Property="IsEditable"
         Value="False" />
      <Setter
         Property="DisplayMemberPath"
         Value="DisplayValue" />
      <Setter
         Property="ItemContainerStyle"
         Value="{StaticResource editingFilteringComboBoxListBoxItem}" />
      <Setter
         Property="Template"
         Value="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" />
   </Style>
```

I want to derive from `ComboBox` but I dont want to include the whole control template for it. I dont even want to touch the control template. I do want to change the `ItemContainerStyle`, which I could do from code, but much nicer if i dont have to.

The other reason why I want this here is because to want access to the internal members of the `ComboBox`'s control template, namely the `TextBox` and the `Popup`. Usually I access members like this in the override of `OnApplyTemplate`.

I feel like im travelling the wrong path, enlighten me sensei.

Comment: you can be my spelling sensei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

false alarm,

i wasnt including a link to this file in my generic.xaml

oh and i didnt have to set the Template value

```
   <Style
      TargetType="{x:Type local:EditingFilteringComboBox}"
      BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
      <Setter
         Property="IsEditable"
         Value="False" />
      <Setter
         Property="DisplayMemberPath"
         Value="DisplayValue" />
      <Setter
         Property="ItemContainerStyle"
         Value="{StaticResource editingFilteringComboBoxListBoxItem}" />
   </Style>
```

the style will only set properties that are different from the base style. so as i dont want to change the control template i simply dont set it. OnApplyTemplate is called, and i can access the internals of the ComboBox's control template.